# django runserver Unable to configure handler 'file': 'ConvertingTuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, django

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': LOG_FILE,
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },

}



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/jie/Sandbox/python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/jie/Sandbox/python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/jie/Sandbox/python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/jie/Sandbox/python3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 86, in configure_logging
    logging_config_func(logging_settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/config.py", line 789, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/config.py", line 565, in configure
    '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': 'ConvertingTuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'


    enter code here
```

Comment: You should actually ask a question, not just post code. And what is LOG_FILE in that settings snippet?

Answer (score 2):

Your LOG_FILE line which you have not shown has an ending comma

Comment: With the same traceback, this is the problem that I had. An incorrectly placed trailing comma converts it into a tuple, which eventually gets transformed into a ConvertingTuple. This can be hit by a comma at the end of a dict _when it is not inside of a larger dict_. The OP does not appear to have this pattern, but probably due to insufficient information. Nice find.